# Xcode Error: Expected type

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, xcode7

```
    - (instancetype)initPrivate
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    [self.dictionary setObject:image forKey:key];
}
- (UIImage *)imageForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    return [self.dictionary objectForKey:key];
}
```

I using dictionary for storing image. i have a problem in setImage method any getImage method.

Comment: I don't have error with your code. Maybe somewhere else. What's the error message exactly? Which line?

Comment: What problem? Please be more descriptive when asking questions.

Comment: i have a Error in -(void )setImage:(UIImage*)image forKey:(NSString*)Key and - (UIImage *)imageForKey:(NSString *)key .

Comment: i have a this Error : Expected a type for this 2line of code.

Comment: try  `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`